# Calculate percentage of multiple prometheus metrics and display in Grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I have the following metrics:

`total_number_of_visitors` which is a `gauge` that increases when a visitor enters the website and decreases when they leave

`paid_visitors` which is a `counter` that is incremented when a paid visitor enters the website and stays for at least 5 minutes.

Each one of these metrics has two common labels `device` [mobile, desktop, other] and `browser` [ Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Edge, other]

I want to calculate a percentage of the a paid visitors using PromQL and filter by any of these two labels to display in a graph in Grafana.
How do I go about that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following query would return the average percentage of paid visitors on the site during the last 5 minutes:

```
100 * rate(paid_visitors[5m]) / avg_over_time(total_number_of_visitors[5m])
```

Filtering by `device` and `browser` labels can be performed in the following way:

```
100 * rate(paid_visitors{device="$device",browser="$browser"}[5m]) / avg_over_time(total_number_of_visitors{device="$device",browser="$browser"}[5m])
```

Just substitute `$device` and `$browser` with the desired values.

Grouping be `device` and `browser` labels can be performed in the following way:

```
100 * sum(rate(paid_visitors[5m])) by (device, browser) / sum(avg_over_time(total_number_of_visitors[5m])) by (device, browser)
```